# pinescript: ta.pivothigh misunderstanding

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to understand what the `ta.pivothigh` method is doing in pinescript V5.

I was expecting that it was looking nearby for the highest price, but when I use a simple script like this:

```
float ph = ta.pivothigh(0, 2)
plot(ph, color = color.blue ,  linewidth = 2)
```

The pivot points are not on the highest price, but there is an offset on the right of 2 bars. This offset is controlled by the '2' value.

Like this:

[image]

I was expecting that the pivot point was exactly where I put the red arrow.

Does someone has en explanation please?

(I have search on stackoverflow, on the official doc etc... but I do not understand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This function returns price of the pivot high point. It returns '**NaN**',
> if there was no pivot high point.
>
> **ARGUMENTS**
> ***leftbars (series int/float)*** Left strength.
> ***rightbars (series int/float)*** Right strength.

It takes two (or three with a *source*) arguments. It will find the pivot high based on the left and right bars arguments.

You can break it down as follows:

1. Pick a candle.
2. There should be no higher high to the left side within the `leftbars` period.
3. There should be no higher high to the right side within the `rightbars` period.
4. If all `true`, then the selected candle is a pivot high.

Looking right is where the delay/offset comes from. If you want to find a pivot point, you need to wait for a few bars (`rightbars`) to confirm the price action. Therefore, there will be some delay and it will be reflected in the plot.

However, `plot*()` functions has an argument called `offset` which you can use.

If you call your `plot()` with the `offset=-2`, it will shift your plot two bars to the left and then your line will align with the pivot points.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

float ph = ta.pivothigh(0, 2)
plot(ph, color = color.blue ,  linewidth = 2)
plot(ph, color = color.green ,  linewidth = 2, offset=-2)
```

[image]